# Getting injector error when trying to use custom Angular Component library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I wrote a custom Angular component library that makes use of the `ComponentFactoryResolver` from `@angular/core` and when I try to import my module into my main application module I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterOutlet -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterOutlet -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver!
```

I have searched around and found other [similar issues](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1348) with `ngx-bootstrap` library doing a similar thing (I think)  and even after looking at the source code for that library I still don't understand what I am doing wrong.  I assume it has something to do with needing to utilize the `forRoot()` static method on my module, but when I started adding an entry for that like this:

```
export class MyCoreModule {
  static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyCoreModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ComponentFactoryResolver, useValue: ComponentFactoryResolver
      }]
    }
  }
 }
```

It fixed that error, but then another one showed up for `Renderer2`. I fixed that one and another one popped up and eventually the code looked like this:

```
export class MyCoreModule {
  static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyCoreModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ComponentFactoryResolver, useValue: ComponentFactoryResolver
      },{
        provide: Renderer2, useValue: Renderer2
      },{
        provide: ViewContainerRef, useValue: ViewContainerRef
      },{
        provide: TemplateRef, useValue: TemplateRef
      },{
        provide: ElementRef, useValue:ElementRef
      }]
    }
  }
 }
```

And I just had a feeling that I was doing something wrong. It didn't seem right that I had to do this for pretty much every Angular core service/component, so I stopped. I also noticed that the `ngx-bootstrap` library didn't have to do anything like this in their "ModalModule" which also uses the `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

Therefore, does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please share a simple github repo where we can reproduce that issue?

Comment: That might take a while, but I might be able to do it in the morning. Something I did just try out is taking all of my custom module that was being served via a private npm package and I threw it into my code directly as if it were apart of the application code and all of a sudden it works just fine. So the issue seems to be related to the fact that the module is externalized if that helps at all.

Comment: With that said, a sample application to reproduce it might be hard since the issue seems to be directly related to the custom module being external to the application. Its private so I can't just add it into a public github somewhere.

Comment: I don't ask you to share the whole library. Just put as minimum code as possible to reproduce the issue. Maybe during this phase you will find out what causes that error.